# Migrate from Vue 2 to NEXT js

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, next.js, migration

I have a vue 2 full front-end application means all the logic is also being handled in the front-end. I want to migrate this app to React with NEXT js 13 where we can actually handle logic in server side and keep client side dummy using react.

How do I migrate from Vue 2 to NEXT js?
I saw there's a custom server option in NEXT.js but I wanna know if there's anyother easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Junaid I have suggest you few points regarding nuxt.js please take look before you migrate your application.

1. Nuxt.js is more time efficiency because it's built on vue.js and your previous code in vue2 that's good point for you because nuxt.js is framework specially developed for vue.js
2. From code migration vue2 to nuxt.js is so easy
3. You also mention Next.js is your option but next.js is primarily made for react.js not for vue.js. If you go with next.js you need to rewrite all your code and logic in react and it take more efforts and time as compare to next.js

I will hope that answer beneficial for you..